# Angular reduce api calls

Tags: angularjs

I am creating one sample application, where I have API call for getting classes say

```
http://localhost:8080/school/4/classes
```

I have created a service for this

```
appServices.service( 'classService', ['$http', '$q', 
  function($http,$q){
    this.getClass = function() {

      var classes = $q.defer()
      $http.get( "http://localhost:8080/school/4/classes" )
        .then(function(data) {
          classes.resolve(data)
        });
      return classes.promise
    }
  }])
```

I have two controllers say ctrl1 and ctrl2, in both I have code for service as

```
 classService.getClass().then(function(data) {
   $scope.classList = data.data.classes
 })
```

My problem is two time api call is happening, can we reduced many api calls to one because my data is not going to be changed. I have already tried with  `{ cache: true }` but no luck

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging your `controller`? When `classService.getClass()` method is getting called? Sometimes (due to bad routing or incorrect event binding) methods might gets called multiple times. So your this piece of code may not have any issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to prevent multiple calls is to use `cache` option:

```
app.service('classService', ['$http', function($http) {
  this.getClass = function() {
    return $http.get('data.json', { cache: true }).then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
  };
}])
```

Note, that you should not use `$q` as it's redundant.

In case if you need more control over the cache you can store reference to resolved promise:

```
app.service('classService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var promise

  this.getClass = function() {
    if (!promise) {
      promise = $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });  
    }

    return promise
  };
}]);
```

And one more pattern with the most flexibility:

```
app.service('classService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
  var data;

  this.getClass = function() {
    return data ? $q.when(data) : $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
      data = response.data;
      return data;
    });
  };
}])
```